# Strange absolute positioned behavior

Tags: jquery, css, positioning

I am using jQuery to add a new div and position it just after the original div. Everything is working fine and the positioning is right, but when I scroll, the absolute positioned div is acting as `fixed` and not scrolling with the content.

Anyone know why this might be?

```
$('[data-tagging]').after('<div id="tagging-msg"></div>');

$('[data-tagging]').on("keyup", function(e) {
    var content = $(this).text();
    var go = content.match(start);
    var name = content.match(word);

    var offset = $(this).offset();
    var height = $(this).outerHeight();
    var width = $(this).outerWidth();

    var top = (offset.top + height) - 3 + "px";
    var left = offset.left + "px";

    $("#tagging-msg").css({position: 'absolute', top: top, left: left, width: width - 10 + 'px'});
});
```

Comment: well, fixed stays to the screen irrespective of scroll.. absolute will still with content.

Comment: Are you sure your `div#tagging-msg`'s parent is not in position:fixed ?

Comment: Is the new div placed on a relative positioned item? could you share the rest of the relevant HTML and its CSS?

Comment: can you make a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) demonstrating the problem?

Answer (score 1):

You should use quotes between CSS properties name

```
$("#tagging-msg").css({'position': 'absolute', 'top': top,...
```